# To give two decimals using printf from doubles and input tsking

Tags: java

```
Expected Input:
x=1.75
y=1.25
z=0.75
The answer is 0.95

This program output:
Enter the value of x:
1.75
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at evaluate.main(evaluate.java:13)




import java.util.Scanner;   //make scanner class available
public class evaluate
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
double x=0.0;
double y=0.0;
double z=0.0;
double ans;
ans=(x*y-y*z)/x*z ;
System.out.println("Enter the value of x:"); //take input 
x=input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the value of y:");
```

> The code is meant to evaluate the expression ansa and produuce an answer to two decimal places having the viriables declared as doubles.
>   Your help is appreciate.

```
y=input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the value of z:");  //take value of z
z=input.nextInt();
System.out.printf("The answer is ","%0.2f%ans",ans); //get to two decimals

}
}
```

Comment: `printf('The answer is %0.2f', ans)`. your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The nextInt function reads ints.  You need to use the nextDouble function to read a double.

Also, you need to do the calculation after you input the doubles.

Comment: Because he gives his input example as 1.75